# Android: product flavor, applicationId (package name) and manifest

Tags: android, gradle

So I have base Application class, DApp.

My flavor application classes just extend the DApp.

for example

> package com.d.android;
>
> public class App extends DApp {}

In my gradle script the following is setup for the flavor:

```
productFlavors {
    d {
        applicationId = "com.d.android"
    }
}
```

In my manifest I've declared my app like that:

```
name = ".App"
```

For some reason gradle does not honor the different package name given by applicationId.

For now I just resolved it by defining AndroidManifest files for each flavor and declaring the full class name for the app file, but that seems wrong. That means that my package name is wrong.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is that you are not specifying a package name. You should always specify the package name in the root of your default android manifest file like this:

package="com.exmaple.app"

Please take a look at this explanation by the Google guys, hope it helps.

http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/applicationid-vs-packagename

Good luck